# Reducible and unfaithful module

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Is this kind of module possible? I have a homework in which i must give an example or prove its not. I can do neither.

We know the following about a reducible unfaithful module:
$$
V = U_1 \oplus U_2 \oplus \dots \oplus U_n,
$$ 
where $U_i$ is irreducible for some $v_i \in V$, and some $g, h \in G$, $g \cdot v_i = h \cdot v_i$.
Any vector in $V$ can be written as a unique sum of vectors in $U_i$.

The uniqueness seems like it might give a contradiction, but I simply can't think of one, try as I might.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, a reducible unfaithful module is possible. For example, take a direct sum of two trivial modules.

Comment: @MattSamuel So what? It is a still an example of a reducible unfaithful module.